# SharePoint 2013 Property Bag CRUD using jQuery (REST API) and CSOM (ECMASCRIPT)

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint-2013, csom

for 2 days i'm going nuts with the property bag in SP 2013 using javascript and CSOM.
I was following this post [example property bag](http://blogs.realdolmen.com/experts/2013/05/22/building-sharepoint-hosted-apps-reading-and-writing-to-property-bags/) about writing and reading property bag keys in SP 2013 using CSOM ... and it works great! However can somebody tell how can `I delete/update a key ?` So in that example, how you can delete the key using CSOM?

Another question: how can I achieve the same (CRUD) using the new REST API in SP 2013 using jQuery? I'm talking about calling the REST endpoint: `http://site_here/_api/web/AllProperties` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can update key value with set_item() method.

There is code snippet:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
clientContext.load(oWebsite);
var webProps = oWebsite.get_allProperties();
clientContext.load(webProps);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler);

function successHandler() {
    var client = webProps.get_fieldValues().Client;
    var newClient = "newClient";
    webProps.set_item("Client", newClient);
}
```

I think it must be possible in REST, as CSOM is just wrapper over REST.
You can get request to `http://yourServer.com/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery` with Fiddler or browser developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the desired approach. Some endpoints are read only while others are read/write: See the table at https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn499819.aspx#bk_WebProperties. I would use the JSOM API to update values when they are not read/write as a rest endpoint.